# Characteristics of a DC motor control system

Tags: dc-motor, control-system

I am designing a DC motor controller model. I have a second order system so the step response oscillates and overshoots the final value somewhat.

I have seen a lot of theory on calculating rise time, settling time, and overshoot.

My question is what effect do these things actually have on a DC motor?

Should I be focused on making the overshoot less or changing the rise time in order for the system to react faster?

Answer (score 1):

The system you are driving with a motor has no effect on transfer characteristics of the motor itself. But it will have an overall effect on the entire group: motor + system. Therefore a cascaded control loop is to be used, where the inner loop is the standard motor controller.

This motor controller can be further split into a two cascaded loops : velocity (voltage) and current (torque). Also a third outer loop is possible, position loop. It all matters what exactly you want to control, what physical value is the input of your system,...etc.